# Google Tasks Reorder Lists

Tags: google-tasks

Okay here's a Google product forum describing the problem:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/calendar/yy1HTCdWTCM/bAsnrvx_BwAJ

Basically, you can't reorganize your task lists in Google Tasks. Yes, you can organize the items within the list, but there seems to be no way of actually organizing which lists are on top and which are on bottom. Has anyone anywhere found a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In September 2020, I noticed that [the web client](https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://mail.google.com) has added grippers to re-order task lists under the list selection dropdown once the mouse hovers over the list name.  (The mobile version does not have this yet.)

[image: Gripper control on Google Tasks list]

Comment: I can't see what you're talking about. Can you send a screen shot

Comment: Sure, I've added a picture

Comment: Oh my gosh, this was a great moment in my life. Seems like they finally added it.

Answer (score 3):

(See also: my accepted answer)

The closest answer that I have is renaming an existing list.

**Edit:** Adding example

If you have:

- List A
- List C
- List B
- List D

And want A B C D, then rename

- List A
- List B -> C
- List C -> B
- List D

This requires emptying out or moving tasks between lists to make sense, but it allows the list order to be as desired.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: Example added.  It's not a great option (Google Tasks needs some work!) but it can help in some situations.